# How can I auto generate a string value for parameter store via cloudformation?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I am using cloudformation to deploy a parameter store via `AWS::SSM::Parameter`. I'd like to generate a random string as the value in this parameter. But I can't find a way to do that in `AWS::SSM::Parameter`.

I know there is a property `GenerateSecretString` for `AWS::SecretsManager::Secret`. Is there something similar with parameter store?

Answer (score 1):

No, not at this moment.

However, you can generate password using shell (or other) to pass it as a parameter, or use [Cloudformation Custom Resource](https://www.itonaut.com/2018/01/03/generate-passwords-in-aws-cloudformation-template/)